# Small inductive dimension of subspace: is regularity needed

Tags: general-topology

Use the definition of small inductive dimension $\operatorname{ind}$ that, for integer $n \geq 0$, space $X$ has $\operatorname{ind} X \leq n$ if at each $x \in X$, for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $X$ with $V \subset U$ and $\operatorname{ind} \operatorname{bdy} V \leq n - 1$.
(In other words, do *not* require such $V$ to have the additional property that $\operatorname{cls} V \subset U$.)

A standard result is that if $Y$ is a subspace of a topological space $X$, then $\operatorname{ind} Y \leq \operatorname{ind} X$.

This appears, for example, as 1.1.2 in Engelking,*Dimension Theory* (1978), but with the hypothesis that $X$ be regular.

Is regularity actually needed? If so, where in the proof is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\ind}{ind}\DeclareMathOperator{\bd}{bd}$No, regularity is not needed for the *small* inductive dimension, however if you look at the *large* inductive dimension instead, regularity is not even enough to get this inequality. I'm not sure how the inequality is proved in Engelking's book, but here is a proof that doesn't use regularity.

**Lemma:** Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$ be any subspace. Then $\ind(A)\leq\ind(X)$.
**Proof:** If $\ind X=-1$ there is nothing to prove, since both $X$ and $A$ are empty. We proceed now by induction, so suppose that for all spaces $Y$ with $\ind Y\leq n-1$ and all $B\subseteq Y$ we know that $\ind B\leq n-1$. We have a space $X$ with $\ind X\leq n$, a subspace $A\subseteq X$, and we want to prove $\ind A\leq n$. Let $a\in A$ and let $G$ be an open nbhd of $a$ in $A$, so that $G=H\cap A$ for some $H\subseteq X$ open. Since $\ind X\leq n$ we can find an open $a\in V\subseteq H$ in $X$ such that $\ind\bd(V)\leq n-1$. Consider now $U=V\cap A$ which is an open neighbourhood of $a$ in $A$. Since we have $\bd^A(U)\subseteq\bd(V)\cap A$, where $\bd^A(U)$ denotes the boundary of $U$ as computed in $A$. By inductive hypothesis $\ind(\bd(V)\cap A)\leq n-1$, since this is a subspace of the $n-1$ dimensional space $\bd(V)$, and so also by inductive hypothesis $\ind(\bd^A(U))\leq n-1$, showing that $\ind A\leq n$.

Comment: That's essentially the same proof that I had, and the same one as in Engelking. I was just suspicious I was overlooking something since Engelking did include the hypothesis of regularity.

Answer (score 1):

It is not used in that particular proof but it is used in some characterizations, for example $\operatorname{ind} X\le n$ iff for every $x\in X$ and every closed set $F$ with $x\notin F$ there is a partition $L$ between $x$ and $F$ such that $\operatorname{ind} L\le n-1$.
A partition, $L$, between $x$ and $F$ is a closed set with the property that $X\setminus L=U\cup V$ with $U$ and $V$ open and disjoint, and such that $x\in U$ and $F\subseteq V$.
This characterization contains a characterization of regularity.